# Right to repair in Halacha

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, transactions, modern-times, intellectual-property

Does Halacha have a perspective on the [right to repair movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_to_repair)? Basically it is a movement to allow people who purchase goods to have the right to repair goods, whereas others argue businesses which sell goods have the right to stipulate they have a monopoly on repairing them when they sell them to consumers.

Comment: If it’s in the contract, it’s in the contract. If it’s not, then it’s not. Not much else to discuss. If you signed the contract, you’re bound by it.

Comment: @Chatzkel broadly speaking yes, though monopoly regulation is a feature of both Jewish and non-Jewish societies

Comment: @AKA - Please remind me where "monopoly regulation is a feature of Jewish society"

Comment: @danny schoemann Price caps are talmudic, I believe

Comment: @AKA - Price caps, yes. (https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/price-regulation-in-jewish-law/).  But monopolies in general or on repairs? If they are not overcharging?

Comment: @DannySchoemann agree. I'm not saying that the takanos are in place already. But the principle set out by chatzkel that society has no place interfering with individuals' contracts is not correct

Comment: @AKA the right to repair is not about monopoly. It’s a way for the companies to continue having a revenue stream even after the sale. There may be ten companies that offer the same product, but once you pick one, they need to repair it. It’s contractual.

Comment: Monopoly is probably the wrong word - it's the idea that companies can make excess profits via market power. Jewish society has always regulated that power. If in this case the profit is excessive it's a valid candidate for regulation